# /var/log/firewalld is not getting rotated

Tags: logrotate, firewalld

I am not sure why this particular file is not getting rotated. It is not a directory. Any ideas?

The size of the firewalld file:

```bsh
$ ls -alh /var/log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root   134M Jan 31 13:49 firewalld
```

The relevant stanza from /etc/logrotate.conf:

```
/var/log/firewalld {
    hourly
    copytruncate
    maxsize 1M
    missingok
    rotate 8
    compress
    notifempty
    nomail
    noolddir
}
```

The command executed:

```bsh
$ sudo logrotate -fv /etc/logrotate.conf

rotating pattern: /var/log/firewalld  forced from command line (8 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, log files >= 1048576 are rotated earlier, old logs are removed
No logs found. Rotation not needed.
set default create context
```

The resulting size of the firewalld file:

```bsh
$ ls -alh /var/log
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root   134M Jan 31 13:49 firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43398163/timeline

Apparently the -v switch is the same as the -n switch; in other words the v-switch will not actually allow logrotate to rotate logs.